# Angular-UI ui-sortable looses sync with bounded array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

First of all let me tell you that I'm a beginner on html/js developing.

Using **angular-ui** to permit sorting a list (ul), when performing **SOME** actions the array looses   synchronization with the list.

Starting with :

```
$scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

and the html:

```
<ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I drag (example) the first *li* element between second and third it changes place inside *ul*, yet the bounded item remains in same position in *list* array.

```
>angular.element($(".ng-scope")).scope().list
["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

I've created an jsfiddle and that behaviour can be tested :
http://jsfiddle.net/DmLt2/

Other strange behaviors can be observed if we play a little bit with it.

**JQuery 1.9.1, JQueryUI 1.10.3, Angular 1.2.2, AngularUI 0.4.0**

Meanwhile, I've found online an jQuery UI Sortable plugin wrapper. With minor changes I've managed to put it working here :
http://jsfiddle.net/42VCK/

Yet its required to remove the reference to AngularUI or change the module name.

Can anyone give me some help to put this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what angular-ui you are using, but it is way old. The latest ui-sortable is hosted at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable . Important note, to use with AngularJS 1.2.x you need to use the ui-sortable branch `angular1.2` as per their readme file: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/tree/angular1.2

Using the above sources the following jsfiddle is based on your example except using the right ui-sortable sources: http://jsfiddle.net/BuLdk/1/

Comment: Thank you Beyers.

I was using an [angular-ui](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js) package that was out of date (or never had updated) . 

Honestly I still have some difficulty in dealing with a myriad of versions, alternative versions, versions that require specific versions of others. For me it's a mess.